# After login when i click a link to another message in a post it redirects me to login page?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

After login when i click a link to another message in a post it redirects me to login page but if i copy the link and remove www from the url it will not redirect me to login page?
I am using ASP.NET and VB.NET in code-behind. This problem arises when i copy the link from url and post in a message, and then click on that link it will redirect to login page. But if i copy the linkl from post without ""http : // www " then it will work fine. 
I searched on google but did not find anything helpful.

Comment: you should check your Site Bindings in the IIS, the site might have  registered bindings without `www`, you should add the required binding.

Comment: how i can check that where this will be located in IIS?

Comment: if you are using IIS7, then select the website and look for `Bindings` options in the menu present on the right side of screen.click on it to add/edit/view the bindings. Moreover you can follow the link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using IIS 7 
Select your application on left side, and click bindings on right side in Bindings tab,
add new binding row "http://*" and "www.*"